# How to Save Sign In/Log In State ('.stat') in Kotlogram?

Tags: api, save, state, telegram

Im using [kotlogram](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWv-Ccr4rSAhXQFsAKHQ2lAb0QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbadoualy%2Fkotlogram&usg=AFQjCNGtOExGAh_Alm_ZeKsFfDVOv323oQ) and i want to know how to save login state into file like '.stat'? what is the correct way to achieve this and what classes are needed then?
Ive done with different versions of telegram api java, but couldn't save a proper and functional state file.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people having the same question: https://kotlogram.readme.io/docs/get-started

When you get a client using

```
Kotlogram.getDefaultClient();
```

You have to specify an DataStorage, the interface describes some methods that you need to implement in order to persist your session.

Read the doc for more details.